# how to get a variable over to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get a variable (which is set when a link is clicked) over to a function and show it as a pop out.

the code as shown below:

```
$('a#link1').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var value = 'true';
});


function exe(){
    alert(value);
}
```

when the function is executed , all i get is value is undentified.

So anyone knows a way around it?

Comment: var value; $('#link1')...{ value = true; }  - if you are using id selector, you don't need to specify the element name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables have scope, you define the `value` variable in the scope of the onclick closure, and it wont be accessible outside it.

The following would work:

```
var value = false; //Define in the global scope

$('a#link1').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    value = false; //Use in a local-scope is legal. 
});

function doSomething()
{
 alert(value);
}
```

However having many global variables will make your project hard to maintain, and there are other more clean solutions available. In general i'd recommend you to read a proper book on programming though :)

Comment: Yep. THe other soloution posted isn't really optimal, since you can run the function without the click and make it fail. Here it is set as default, so it won't fail, even if it is run outside the click :)

Comment: No problem, its good that i could help you. However if you are serious about web-development i strongly recommend you to keep learning by purchasing a proper book. Variable scope is essential to programming, and could be a hard concept to grasp (especially in that wonky language called javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Just make the variable global, or better yet "attach" it to the element using the `.data()`:

```
$('a#link1').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $(this).data("value", "true");
});
```

Then you can always check for this:

```
function exe() {
    alert($('a#link1').data("value"));
}
```

Note that it was added in jQuery 1.2.3 guess that by now it doesn't really matter though.